# mongoose: adding a single subdocument to a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I add a single subdocument to a mongoose document?  Consider the following scenario written in typescript:

```
ParentSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    child: ChildSchema
});

ChildSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

and I would like to add a new child to the parent whenever I create a new parent.  For my code example, the new parent is created but the child is never added to the parent.  The child keeps displaying as null.  Here is my current save logic:

```
let parentdoc = new this._model(iparent);//base repository protetected member

      parentdoc.save((err: any, result: IParentModel) => {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          }

          result.child = new Child(child);
          result.update(null, (err: Error, results1: IParentModel) => {
              if (err) {
                  reject(err);
              }

                  resolve(result1);
          });
      });


where this._model = mongoose.model<IParentModel>("Parent", ParentSchema)
```

What, in this code, would cause the parent to save and not the child?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not sending any values to the update method, so you can save the document again to add the child to the parent:

```
parentdoc.save((err: any, result: IParentModel) => {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          }

          result.child = new Child(child);
          result.save(null, (err: Error, results1: IParentModel) => {
              if (err) {
                  reject(err);
              }

                  resolve(result1);
          });
      });
```

Or set the child in the update method:

```
parentdoc.save((err: any, result: IParentModel) => {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          }

          const child1 = new Child(child);
          result.update(null, { $set: { child: child1, } }, null, (err: Error, results1: IParentModel) => {
              if (err) {
                  reject(err);
              }

                  resolve(result1);
          });
      });
```